# How can I pass all the values from my csv file to fit_transform?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, nlp, tf-idf

```
for i in range(1,6):
    df1 = pd.read_csv('./starReviews/' + str(i)  + 'Star.csv')
    tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
    doc_vec = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(df1.loc[0])
```

I want to pass all the values of my csv file to fit_transform but currently I am only able to pass the first line. Anyone know how I'd pass everything at once?

Comment: df1.loc[0] will select only the 0th index of your input dataframe.
Instead of .loc, pass the complete column containing the text to the TfidfVectorizer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, this works for your solution, use .values attribute of a dataframe

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('./TfidfVectorizer_sklearn.xlsx')
for i in df.columns: # loop through every column
    tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
    print(df.loc[:, i].values)
    X = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(df.loc[:, i].values) # select column all values
    print(tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names_out())
    print(X.shape)
```